# Как создать shared библиотеку cmake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

Я пользуюсь VS code + Cmake. Мне надо, чтобы один мой h файл был динамической библиотекой. После этого запускать функции из этого файла

Comment: А как он будет запускаться, если вы создаете dll? Может вам нужно заменить `add_library` на `add_executable`?

Comment: Тогда что у вас не запускается? Этот проект запускаться не будет, потому что это dll

Comment: @AntonShchyrov мне нужно создать библиотеку SHARED и запустить программу изпользуя функции из нее. И я не знаю, как это сделать

Comment: Ну так у вас должно быть два проекта